# Why does the trailer of this pdf not conform PDF standard?

Tags: pdf

Section 7.5.5 of to [pdf ISO 32000-1](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) says that

> The trailer of a PDF file enables a conforming reader to quickly find the cross-reference table and certain
>   special objects. Conforming readers should read a PDF file from its end. The last line of the file shall contain
>   only the end-of-file marker, %%EOF. The two preceding lines shall contain, one per line and in order, the
>   keyword startxref and the byte offset in the decoded stream from the beginning of the file to the beginning of
>   the xref keyword in the last cross-reference section. The startxref line shall be preceded by the trailer
>   dictionary, consisting of the keyword trailer followed by a series of key-value pairs enclosed in double angle
>   brackets (<<…>>) (using LESS-THAN SIGNs (3Ch) and GREATER-THAN SIGNs (3Eh)).

But I found [this](https://dn-tuna-podcast.qbox.me/attachment/2016-10-15-nfc-and-rfid.pdf) pdf file does not follow this rule, though It may be opened by pdfviewer without any trouble. Specifically, the last 5 lines of this file is

```
trailer
<</Size 352/ID[<9257C760F49955A23047D72C37914E79>       <82F1302E14912449A9BB43536F853CD6>]>>
startxref
116
%%EOF
```

Clearly this trailer dictionary is not correct, since the standard says that this dictionary must contain an entry with `Root` as the key, which this trailer does not have. Then I found that the offset 116 point to another xref table, which is located almost at the beginning of the file, and followed by another trailer which indeed contains a `Root entry`.

```
xref
352 24
0000000016 00000 n
0000001914 00000 n
0000001980 00000 n
0000002147 00000 n
... ...
trailer
<</Size 376/Root 353 0 R/Info 351 0 R/ID[<9257C760F49955A23047D72C37914E79><82F1302E14912449A9BB43536F853CD6>]/Prev 4183097>>
```

Comment: Do you want something more concrete than "The software used to generate it does not produce 100% compliant PDFs"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe looks like a linearized PDF. As you already reference the PDF specification, you should, therefore, also have a look at *Annex F (normative) Linearized PDF*, in particular in section *F.3.11 Main Cross-Reference and Trailer (Part 11)*:

> The main trailer has no **Prev** entry and shall not contain any entries other than **Size**.

Thus, at least for linearized PDFs the trailer does not need to have the entries you are looking for. Strictly speaking there actually is a different error in that final trailer of your sample file: It contains an **ID** entry in spite of the requirement that it *shall not contain any entries other than **Size***.

In F.3.1 you'll find an example of the end of a linearized PDF:

```
trailer
<< /Size 43>>% Trailer need not contain other entries; in particular,
% it should not have a Prev entry
% Offset of first-page cross-reference table (part 3)
startxref
257
%%EOF
```

Comment: I added few more considerations along the way in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70564329/213871).

Answer (score 0):

I think @Richard is right in the sense that the section *7.5.5 File Trailer* of *ISO 32000-1:2008* seems to be quite outdated and lacks contextual integration with the specification of linearized PDFs and also XRef streams. The consequences of this lacking integration is that:

- The last `startxref` line is preceded by the trailer dictionary of the **last** incremental update only if the document is non linearized and does not have cross-reference streams;
- If the document has cross-reference streams the trailers is the dictionary of the object pointed by the `startxref` directive;
- If the document is linearized and has cross-reference tables the last `startxref` line is preceded by the trailer of main cross-reference table (see *F.3.11 Main Cross-Reference and Trailer*).

As an implicit consequence of the integrated specification only documents with cross-reference streams can efficiently determine in advance the size of the XRef entries table in the document (see entry `/Size` in *Table 15 – Entries in the file trailer dictionary*).

Comment: Beware, you mix incremental updates and linearized PDFs here. While indeed the mechanisms of incremental updates are used in linearized PDFs, there is no incremental update in a linearized PDF. Furthermore, I cannot follow your argumentation. The effects of linearization is essentially identical in stream and table cases.

Comment: I understand the abuse of the "incremental update" mechanism to implement linearized PDFs. My point was trying to find invariant rules that apply in general when all the specification features are considered. I used these invariants to fix a bug in my pdfmm library (ex-PoDoFo), that was reporting warnings for a perfectly valid linearized PDF. These invariants maybe are not perfectly worded but they should make the point when implementing PDF parsing routines.