How to convert Docx to PDF using Aspose.Words and apply PDF Bates and PDF layout on same PDF using Aspose.PDF.Drawing?
I am working on cross platform. I am trying to convert Docx file to pdf. My requirement is to after converted Docx into PDF add the PDF bates and Page layout on pdf file.
I am using following code:
 Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document(Source);

 doc.Save(Destination, Aspose.Words.SaveFormat.Pdf);

 using (FileStream pdfStream = new FileStream(Destination, FileMode.Open, 
 FileAccess.Read))
 {
     Aspose.Pdf.Document pdfDoc = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(pdfStream);//This line 
     having issue "Aspose.Pdf.InvalidPdfFileFormatException: Trailer not found "

    pdfDoc.Save("created.pdf");
  }

This gives me an error like "Aspose.Pdf.InvalidPdfFileFormatException: Trailer not found "
For this code I am using
Aspose.Words 24.5.0
Aspose.PDF.Drawing 24.4.0
Can you please provide me the solution. And how to apply the settings like bates number and paper layout.

Read following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667874/why-does-the-trailer-of-this-pdf-not-conform-pdf-standard

The question is answered in Aspose support forum here https://forum.aspose.com/t/converted-docx-to-pdf-file-giving-issue-while-adding-in-aspose-pdf/284653
